# Unable to build GStreamer pipeline; no element x265enc in Android

Tags: android, plugins, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, libx265

I am trying to implement H265 using the x265enc encoder in an android application using GStreamer. I have constructed the pipeline which works when using the terminal and gst-launch-1.0 and videotestsrc. However, when trying to execute the pipeline in android it doesn't work and gives the error gst_error_factory_make: no such element factory "x265enc"! and is unable to build the pipeline due to the element x265enc missing.

I have installed plugins-bad (contains x265enc) on the computer and it is in the android.mk file. When I look in the plugins.mk file I don't see x265 mentioned anywhere (x264 is mentioned and x264enc works). Is this an issue? Is there another way to install x265enc so that android can recognize it?

Answer (score 0):

try to install gst-plugins-ugly-1.0 and it will solve your issue

Comment: I don't believe this comment is correct. It seems at this time of the original post and my comment, that the x265enc plugin is not build using the Cerbero build system for gstreamer, and is thus not distributed for Android or MacOS